# Hackerrank Python Input

Tags: python, input, stdin

I'm having trouble with what seems like a basic challenge from HackerRank. It is a unit conversion problem at [Unit Conversion](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cornell-university-high-school-competition-warm-up-1/challenges/unit-conversion), but I'm struggling with the basics: How do I read the input in Python? I already know that `x = int(input())` reads the first line of input and that `input.split()` separates the input by whitespaces.

But in this particular challenge, there's multiple lines of input! How do I even begin to read all of those lines with Python? I can't possibly assign 7 variables to just read 7 lines! And some lines contain both strings and integers! How do I store the strings and integers in seperate lists? I'm so confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Problem:**

The input will begin with a line containing 2 numbers x and y meaning that "x of unit A" is equal to "y of unit B". For instance, if A is "kilos" and B is "pounds" one possibility is x = 3.25 and y = 7.165024.

The next line will contain a single integer N, containing the number of conversions to be performed.

Each of the next N lines will be of the form "z q" where z is a number and q is either 'A' or 'B'.

Output N lines with a number each. See the sample input/output for further details.

**Sample Input:**

[image]

**Sample Output:**

[image]

Comment: https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/219617888-Using-STDIN-for-inputs-and-STDOUT-for-outputs

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvotes. I'm sincerely looking for some answers and yet I'm rebuked this way? Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hackerrank, pair inputs are mostly space separated. Like in your case it's after 5, number letter.
The cases will differ on the basis of test cases, 5 for now. But you do have three things that you know, x y & number. You could use the split function for getting x&y after reading the line, then create dictionary or two diff lists to store them in pairs.